# RegEx c#: regex expression that does not contain substring but ends with _Number

Tags: c#, regex, numbers, substring

I wanted to find string that does not contains substrings (test,Test, back, Back, Down, down) and ends with _number e.g.

```
test_02.txt -- False
Final_test_02.txt -- False
final_02.txt -- True
final_3.txt -- True
final_17.txt -- True
Down-05.txt -- False
```

How to do this efficiently with Regular Expression. I am new to RegEx. I have tried

```
((.*)^(test|Test|back|Back|Down)(.*)_\d)
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Why is `Down-05.txt` false?

Comment: @anubhava Because OP wants underbar before number.

Comment: No it should `_number` no `-number` to become false

Comment: and also the input string won't contain substring down.

Comment: You want to find a string? According to your statement "`final_0` \ntestBackdown" will be true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
^(?!.*?(?:[Tt]est|[Bb]ack|[Dd]own)).*?_\d+\.[^.\n]+$
```

Use negative lookahead assertion to match the strings which won't contain a particular substring.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sY1nH4/4)